# How to fix trouble install wine in ubuntu 16?

Tags: wine

I meet a trouble when I try to install wine, like this : [http://imgur.com/a/kcX3C](https://imgur.com/a/kcX3C) . Can you tell me where I was wrong and how to fix this trouble? I want install lastest version of wine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sudo apt-get install -f (not sudo apt-get install -f wine 1.8)? as suggested on the last line of your screenshot?

Comment: Thank you, Charles Gingras. I just fasting fix my problem and it work.